# How to notify once a batch in an SQS queue is done?

Tags: message-queue, distributed, amazon-sqs

I have a batch of `n` messages in an SQS queue and a number of workers. These workers take messages from the queue, process them, and then delete them if they are successful. Once all the workers finish this batch of `n` messages, I want to perform an additional action. The only problem is figuring out when a batch is complete.

One way to do it is to check that the queue is empty. When I take a look at the SQS API, the only thing that seems close is the `ApproximateNumberOfMessages` attribute you get from `GetQueueAttributes`. However, the word "approximate" suggests that it really isn't intended for what I have in mind, and that its purpose is more for scaling up and down the number of workers based on roughly how many messages are in the queue.

What would be the standard way to achieve what I want? Or is SQS ill-fit for this purpose?

Comment: How do you define a batch?

Comment: A batch is just a bunch of messages that are put into the queue at roughly the same time. With something like this, I do have to be careful of separating out batches of work, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQS doesn't really have any built-in mechanisms for grouping messages.  Furthermore, SQS doesn't guarantee that a particular message won't be processed more than once<sup>[[1]](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/DistributedQueues.html#DistributedQueues-at-least-once-delivery)</sup>, so you can't simply count the number of messages processed.

Instead, you'll probably need to track each message individually in an external datastore, and then after each message is processed, check to see if there are any remaining messages.

For instance:

1. As you enqueue each message in the group to the original queue, record the [message ID](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/ImportantIdentifiers.html#ImportantIdentifiers-message-ids) in an external database along with a group number of your own invention.
2. After a worker processes a message, the worker should get the group number for that message from the database (or just include the group number as an [attribute](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/SQSMessageAttributes.html) in the original message), and delete the message ID from the database (if it wasn't already deleted by another worker, which could happen if two workers got the same message from the queue).  The worker should then enqueue a new message containing the group number into a second queue.
3. Another worker reads messages containing the group number from the second queue, and checks the database to see if any of the original messages for that group number remain.  If there are any, this worker does nothing.  If there are no more messages for the group, this worker performs your additional action.  Be mindful that due to SQS' distributed nature, this final message could also be processed more than once, so the additional action should be idempotent (or at least somehow check to see if it has been performed already).

With this setup, you'll be able to run multiple unrelated batches through the system simultaneously.

Comment: [Disclaimer, author of service], I wanted to point out that there is https://github.com/paradoxical-io/carlyle which i made to facilitate exactly this problem. It helps you track items across the queue in an efficient way.  Hopefully it helps someone else who comes across this problem as well

Answer (score 0):

You could consider adding a bit of code to your worker process(es) that starts a timer of some sort when it asks for a message to process and gets nothing back; if you worker asks for messages, processes messages and then delete messages, and as you say the 'batch' is just a collection of messages recieved arund the same time, then presumably if 5 minutes (or some other user-defined period) goes by and no new messages are returned after repeated requests, you might be able to kick-off your 'after batch' process. This will be more accurate if you can scale down your worker process to just one by the time it gets to the end of the queue (so you can be sure that other nodes are not still processing).

This is by no means perfect - and will depend on the flow / timing of your messages and the criticality of defining what belongs in a 'batch' and what does not.

Alternatively, if at the front-end you know the precise number of messages that get put into a batch, you could count down the number of processed messages and know you are down when you get down to zero.

Comment: How would I count down this number of processed messages?

Comment: You'd need to store it someplace, such as in a seperate memcached/redis cache - someplace that is not tied directly to the running instance but is available to all of them